# Why does light in lenses always tend to take the slowest way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

When a lightray goes through a convex or concave lens it doesn't take the direction where the lens is the thinnest but the thickest. Why does light do that?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lens1b.svg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lens1.svg

Comment: What is your proof that it takes the slowest way? The links you provide do not say so.

Comment: Because the length the light is spending in the slowest material (glass) is in both cases the longest, compared if they had taken the other direction. But of course it depends on the track you take but there isn't any objective choice to make.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is backwards. The path the light follows between two points isn't the slowest path, but the one with the least travel time. This is known as [Fermat's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle). There is a classic analogous problem in the calculus of related rates of change where, for example, a lifeguard goes one speed on land ($v_L$), and another in the water ($v_w < v_L$), find the path the lifeguard should take to get to a drowning swimmer if the lifeguard is $y_L$ from the water's edge, the swimmer is $y_s$ from the water's edge, and the swimmer is $x$ meters down the beach from the lifeguard; now find the path that gets to the drowning victim in the least time.

While the lifeguard example is easier to understand, it leads to the question: how does the light know which way to go to take the least time? The answer to that is that the light doesn't really take one path. It travels in waves that go in every direction, and the net result of adding up all of the effects of the wave is that it travels along the direction of least time.

Comment: But how to understand that the least travel time is in a lens where  the glass is the thickest. Why does it go in a concave lens outward and not inward where he has a totally faster speed and does it make a difference if the light is going up or down?

Comment: The picture that I first learned in high school was to imagine the light as if it were a truck or a cart or anything with two wheels. Now, picture the light entering the glass. The first wheel to enter the glass starts moving slower, forcing the truck to turn because the outside wheel is moving faster. Once the outside wheel enters the glass it goes in a straight line again until it exits, where the reverse process happens.

Comment: As for how this fits in with the least time picture, you'll just have to do the calculations yourself to see that the reduced speed in the glass is balanced by a shorter path.

Comment: The mnemonic of the truck is a good way to explain, but does this mnemonic also has something to do with reality? I mean is it really the cause that lightrays bend due to the fact that one site of a photonwave is sooner bend?

Comment: The reality behind the waves is a little harder to explain in detail - it has to do with components of the wave number, $\vec{k}$, and boundary conditions across the surface. Fermat's principle is sufficient - if you do the math right, the path the light takes is always the one that requires the least time to traverse.